# Python - TypeError while implementing merge sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

So I am new to python and am learning list manipulation currently. Below is the program that I have written to perform a merge sort on my list. However, while compiling, I get an error in line 3-

```
while len(lista) != 0 and len(listb) != 0:
    TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

How can I fix this?

```
def mergesort(lista, listb):
    listc = []
    while len(lista) != 0 and len(listb) != 0:
        if lista[0] > listb[0]:
            listc.append(listb[0])
            listb.remove(listb[0])
        else:
            listc.append(lista[0])
            lista.remove(lista[0])

    if len(lista) == 0:
        listc += listb
    else:
        listc += lista

    print(listc)

def merge(list):
    if len(list) == 0 or len(list) == 1:
        return list
    else:
        mid = len(list) // 2
        lista = merge(list[:mid])
        listb = merge(list[mid:])
        return mergesort(lista, listb)

list = [15, 12, 14, 17, 13, 11, 12, 16, 15]
merge(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is confusing and flawed:

- the sorting function is called `merge` and the merging function is called `mergesort`. This is exactly the opposite of any classic implementation.
- the merging function does not return anything, hence `lista` and `listb` get set to `None` from the recursive calls and `mergesort` applies `len` to arguments that are not lists.

Here is a modified version:

```py
def merge(lista, listb):
    listc = []
    while len(lista) != 0 and len(listb) != 0:
        if lista[0] > listb[0]:
            listc.append(listb[0])
            listb.remove(listb[0])
        else:
            listc.append(lista[0])
            lista.remove(lista[0])

    if len(lista) == 0:
        listc += listb
    else:
        listc += lista

    return listc

def mergesort(list):
    if len(list) < 2:
        return list
    else:
        mid = len(list) // 2
        lista = mergesort(list[:mid])
        listb = mergesort(list[mid:])
        return merge(lista, listb)

list = [15, 12, 14, 17, 13, 11, 12, 16, 15]
mergesort(list)
```

Comment: Thanks its working now. I had later used the return statement  before in the merge function but the indentation was wrong but it's wokring smooth now

Comment: @zsasz: python's style where structure is defined by indentation comes at a hefty price: it makes code very brittle (easy to break).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use `list` as identifier.

In your merge function, in else block, you're returning whats being returned by mergesort function. And in mergesort function, you're returning nothing.

Also, due to recursion in merge function, you're ending up setting variables `lista` and `listb` to returned values of merge function which might be none since `mergesort` isn't returning anything(thus None).

When you send those `lista` and `listb` in mergesort as arguments, you actually send None in such cases, and thus you get error when you try getting their length by `len` function.

To remove error, you can either send modified results to merge, or either can work on the list which is available in both function's scope.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your merge function, the lista and listb are becoming None and getting passed to the function
Also your merge_sort function is not correct.
You can handle your error by using this code below:

```
def mergesort(lista, listb):
    listc = []
    if not lista or not listb:
        return None
    while len(lista) != 0 and len(listb) != 0:
        if lista[0] > listb[0]:
            listc.append(listb[0])
            listb.remove(listb[0])
        else:
            listc.append(lista[0])
            lista.remove(lista[0])


    if len(lista) == 0:
        listc += listb
    else:
        listc += lista

    print(listc)

def merge(list):
    if len(list) == 0 or len(list) == 1:
        return list
    else:
        mid = len(list) // 2
        lista = merge(list[:mid])
        listb = merge(list[mid:])
        return mergesort(lista,listb)


list = [15, 12, 14, 17, 13, 11, 12, 16, 15]
merge(list)
```

Comment: what exactly does the if not lista or not listb statement do? Your version is working but it returns it in multiple sorted lists of 2 elements.

Comment: Thats what i told , i just told you how to hande such errors, the merge list function needs to be modified , the not lista or not listb checks if any one is None and if it is ,  it returns

Comment: you can accept the answers if you have found it useful